# mysql select query with multiple WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select few rows in 1 query by it's ID , for example here is something that i wrote

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = "15 , 14 , 14"
```

how can it be done in real sql query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id IN ( "15" , "14" )
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (14,15);
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest option and is more efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (14,15)
```

However using instructions `OR` is not wrong

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = 14 OR post_id = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR / AND in where condition. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '13' OR post_id = '14' OR post_id = '15'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id BETWEEN 14 and 15
```